# How to install external CMake project to CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR

Tags: cmake, sdl-2

I am trying to link SDL2 to my executable with CMake.

Here is how my project directory looks like now. Basically, I downloaded [SDL2 source code](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.8.tar.gz) from their website and pasted it under projectRoot.

```
projectRoot/
    SDL2/
        include/
        cmake/
        ...
        CMakeLists.txt
        SDL2Config.cmake
    CMakeLists.txt
```

I tried adding SDL2 as a subdirectory like below (projectRoot/CMakeLists.txt):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (myProject)

# SDL
add_subdirectory (SDL2 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
target_include_directories (SDL2 PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${SDL2_SOURCE_DIR}/include>)

set (
    SOURCE_FILES
    src/game.cpp
    src/main.cpp
    src/sdlwrapper.cpp
)
add_executable (my_executable ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_include_directories (my_executable PRIVATE src)
target_link_libraries (my_executable SDL2)
```

While this works on my linux environment, it fails to link dll files on my Windows machine.

I think it would be easier if I could install SDL2 somewhere under projectRoot and use `find_package` to find its targets, so that I would be able to link my executable to its libraries.

1. Is it possible to install external CMake project during configure time?
2. How should I find external project's targets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ExternalProject_Add(external_sdl
    PREFIX "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external"
    URL "https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.8.tar.gz"
    URL_HASH SHA256=edc77c57308661d576e843344d8638e025a7818bff73f8fbfab09c3c5fd092ec
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/installed
    )
set_target_properties(external_sdl PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
```

Build `external_sdl` target.

---

Using the library

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)
link_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/installed/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
target_include_directories(my_executable
    PRIVATE
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/installed/${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
)
```

also

```
find_package(... HINTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/installed/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

see [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/find_package.html)

---

**Bonus**: If you have multiple external projects, instead of building them one by one, you can create (parent) `external_all` empty target and make it depend on all external projects.

```
add_custom_target(external_all)
set_target_properties(external_all PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)

ExternalProject_Add(external_sdl ...)
add_dependencies(external_all external_sdl)

ExternalProject_Add(external_whatever ...)
add_dependencies(external_all external_whatever)
```

Comment: But then how can I link libraries from those ExternalProject? I cannot just do target_link_libraries(myexecutable SDL2) with this setup.

Comment: Everything is in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external/installed` directory. You must instruct CMake to look for headers and libraries there. I updated the answer with more info.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that and come back to you with results.

Comment: Ok Here is what I did: Write `CMakeLists.txt.in` file that downloads & installs ExternalProjects, and use `configure_file` to copy that file into the build directory; Run cmake on that file with `execute_process`. After that, I could do `find_package` and `target_link_libraries` like you did in your answer. It is not exactly what you did, but it works great so far. Thank you

Comment: This is something new, thank you for sharing. Usually I build my project twice: build external projects, reload cmake, build my_executable.